# Find all values on $[0,2\pi)$ such that $\theta_0$ produces the tip of a petal (maximum magnitude of r) all values for which r=0, and sketch a graph?

Tags: geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIUe1.jpg)

A) Find all values on [0,2\pi) such that theta produces the tip of a petal (maximum magnitude of r) all values for which r=0, and sketch a graph?

a) $r = 5 \sin 2 \theta$

b) $r = 5 \sin 3 \theta$

c) $r = 5 \sin 4 \theta$

B) considering what you can observe in the previous graphs, what are general guidelines for number, length and position of petals for a general rose curve: $r = a \sin b \theta$.

c) A polar curve in the form $r = d + a \sin (\theta_0)$ is called a limacon and has several distinct variations, including a cardioid and a limacon with an inner loop. Create general guidelines for when these variations occur and explain what causes them to occur?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A, B, and C this my question

Comment: pie is something you eat, or to be interpreted as $\pi e$.  $\pi$ is pi.  thita doesn't mean anything.  $\theta$ is theta.  thita0 is $thita0=0$.

Comment: how to solve this problem? please help me

Comment: What angles give you the maximum values of $\sin(\theta)$? Now divide these by $2$, $3$, and $4$ (for parts A, B, and C).